# Realm add(_, update: true) removes existing relationships

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am facing an issue where I am unable to keep existing relationships after calling `add(_, update: true)` function.

I wrote a TaskSync class that is responsible for creating/updating Task objects:

```
class TaskSync: ISync {

    typealias Model = Task

    func sync(model: Task) {

        let realm = try! Realm()

        let inWrite = realm.isInWriteTransaction

        if !inWrite {
            realm.beginWrite()
        }

        let _task = realm.object(ofType: Task.self, forPrimaryKey: model.id)

        // Persist matches as they are not getting fetched with the task
        if let _task = _task {
            print("matches: \(_task.matches.count)")
            model.matches = _task.matches
        }

        realm.add(model, update: true)

        if _task == nil {
            var user = realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: model.getUser().id)

            if (user == nil) {
                user = model.getUser()

                realm.add(user!, update: true)
            }

            user!.tasks.append(model)
        }

        if !inWrite {
            try! realm.commitWrite()
        }
    }

    func sync(models: List<Task>) {

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {
            models.forEach { task in
                sync(model: task)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When a model is to be synced, I check if it already exists in the Realm and if so, I fetch it and try to include the `matches` property as this one is not included in the model.

Right before the call `realm.add(model, update: true)`, model contains list of `matches`, however right after the realm.add is executed, the `matches` list is empty.

Here are the two models:

```
class Task: Object, ElementPreloadable, ElementImagePreloadable, ItemSectionable {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var desc: String = ""
    dynamic var price: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var calculatedPrice: Float = 0.0
    dynamic var location: String = ""
    dynamic var duration: Int = 0
    dynamic var date: String = ""
    dynamic var category: Category?
    dynamic var currency: Currency?
    dynamic var longitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var latitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var state: Int = 0
    dynamic var userId: Int = 0

    // Existing images
    var imagesExisting = List<URLImage>()
    // New images
    var imagesNew = List<Image>()
    // Images deleted
    var imagesDeleted = List<URLImage>()

    private let users = LinkingObjects(fromType: User.self, property: "tasks")
    var user: User?

    var matches = List<Match>()

    dynamic var notification: Notification?

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["imagesExisting", "imagesNew", "imagesDeleted", "user", "tmpUser"]
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    func getImageMain() -> URLImage? {
        for image in imagesExisting {
            if image.main {
                return image
            }
        }
        return imagesExisting.first
    }

    func getSection() -> Int {
        return state
    }

    func getSectionFieldName() -> String? {
        return "state"
    }

    func getId() -> Int {
        return id
    }

    func getURL() -> URL? {
        if let image = getImageMain() {
            return image.getResizedURL()
        }
        return nil
    }

    func getState() -> TaskOwnState {
        return TaskOwnState(rawValue: state)!
    }

    func getUser() -> User {
        return (user != nil ? user : users.first)!
    }
}

class Match: Object, ElementPreloadable, ElementImagePreloadable, ItemSectionable {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var state: Int = -1
    dynamic var priorityOwnRaw: Int = 0
    dynamic var priorityOtherRaw: Int = 0
    dynamic var user: User!

    var messages = List<Message>()

    private let tasks = LinkingObjects(fromType: Task.self, property: "matches")
    var task: Task?

    dynamic var notification: Notification?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["task"]
    }

    func getId() -> Int {
        return id
    }

    func getSection() -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func getURL() -> URL? {
        if let image = user.getImageMain() {
            return image.getResizedURL()
        }
        return nil
    }

    func getPriorityOwn() -> PriorityType {
        if priorityOwnRaw == PriorityType.normal.rawValue {
            return PriorityType.normal
        }
        else {
            return PriorityType.favorite
        }
    }

    func getPriorityOther() -> PriorityType {
        if priorityOtherRaw == PriorityType.normal.rawValue {
            return PriorityType.normal
        }
        else {
            return PriorityType.favorite
        }
    }

    func getSectionFieldName() -> String? {
        return nil
    }

    func getTask() -> Task {
        return (task != nil ? task : tasks.first)!
    }
}
```

I spent hours trying to figure out why I am unable to keep the matches relationship when updating the task. Every advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5217) was also asked upon Realm's GitHub issue tracker. For posterity, here is the solution.

[List properties should always be declared as `let` properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes), as assigning to them does not do anything useful. The correct way to copy all objects from one `List` to another is `model.tasks.append(objectsIn: _user.tasks)`.

Comment: I was about to link it here. Thanks for doing it instead :-)